# Unmarshalling SOAP response using java

Tags: java, performance, web-services, soap, saxparser

I am hitting a soap API and it is giving me soap xml response. I have stored that response in String.
Now I am using following code to unmarshal soap xml to JAVA, the code is working fine, but thisunmarshalling is causing performance issue.

```
public static <T> T unmarshallResponse(final String response, final Class<T> responseType) {
        final XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        try (final InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
            final XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = xif.createXMLStreamReader(stream);
            while (xmlStreamReader.hasNext()) {
                if (xmlStreamReader.isStartElement()
                        && responseType.getSimpleName().equals(xmlStreamReader.getLocalName())) {
                    break;
                }
                xmlStreamReader.next();
            }
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jxc.createUnmarshaller();
            return unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStreamReader, responseType).getValue();
        } catch (JAXBException | IOException | XMLStreamException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception occurred at the time of unmarshall the response " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Can some one suggest how can I improve performance of unmarshalling SOAP response.It will be a great help. Is there any better way  of unmarshalling SOAP responses

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on the performance issue ? Is it slow ? or is it consuming more memory ? or is it crashing ?

Comment: It is slow...It is taking much time